# How to dynamically build route values in C# Razor Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to set up a page that lets me filter by various parameters. The filters are nullable parameters to the controller.

For example I have 3 filters, A, B and C. I would like to have different links that set a, b and c to different values, while keeping the other values unchanged.

Currently, I do this like this:

```
    @{
    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(Model.routeValues);

    var temp  = routeValues["a"];
    routeValues["a"] = "1";
    @Html.ActionLink("A = 1","Index",routeValues)
    routeValues["a"] = "2";
    @Html.ActionLink("A = 2","Index",routeValues)
    routeValues["a"] = temp

    temp  = routeValues["b"];
    routeValues["b"] = "1";
    @Html.ActionLink("B = 1","Index",routeValues)
    routeValues["b"] = "2";
    @Html.ActionLink("B = 2","Index",routeValues)
    routeValues["b"] = temp

    temp  = routeValues["c"];
    routeValues["c"] = "1";
    @Html.ActionLink("C = 1","Index",routeValues)
    routeValues["c"] = "2";
    @Html.ActionLink("C = 2","Index",routeValues)
    routeValues["c"] = temp
}
```

I was hoping that there was a cleaner way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Yec... Ungly!!! Just mount every route variation directly in the controller and pass this list inside the model!

Comment: Huh, what do you mean every route variation? This is just an example, I am looking for a scalable solution?